# Extreme Newbie - Attempting to have a meta's content change on jquery button press

Tags: jquery, html

First code snippet is the meta, second + third is when the meta is called (??? terminology?), and the final is... my attempt at having the Post Background change colour when a button is pressed. I'm not sure what I'm doing, or what I'm doing wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#backtosafety').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').fadeToggle('fast');
    $('body').toggleClass('toggle-control');
    $('#backtosafety').fadeOut();
    $('body').css('background-color', '#000').css('color', '#fff');
    $('body').css('text-color', '#red').css('color', '#ff0000')
    $('body')
    $('a').css('color', '#ff0000');
  });
});
```

```css
#entries {
  {
    block: IndexPage
  }
  width: calc( {
    select: Post Size
  }
  + 42px);
  {
    /block: IndexPage
  }
  {
    block: PermalinkPage
  }
  width: 582px;
  {
    /block: PermalinkPage
  }
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: justify;
}

.post {
  background: {
    color: Post Background
  }
  ;
  padding: 15px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: {
    text: Post Margin
  }
  ;
  border: 1px solid {
    color: Border
  }
  ;
  {
    block: IndexPage
  }
  width: {
    select: Post Size
  }
  ;
  {
    /block: IndexPage
  }
  {
    block: PermalinkPage
  }
  width: 540px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  {
    /block: PermalinkPage
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="color:Post Background" content="#d55246">
```

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change meta tags name to a better one.
However, this is how you do it:

```
$('meta[name=NAME-OF-TAG]').attr('content', 'new value');
$('meta[name=description]').attr('content', 'new value');
```

In your case:

```
$('meta[name=color:Post Background]').attr('content', 'new value');
```